# Images don't reflect versioning in Rich Text Fields

Tags: content-editor, media-library, richtext-editor, versions

The Sitecore version for this issue is 9.1.0 (rev. 001564).

In content editor, if I add a versioned image with only 1 version created added to a rich text field on an item, I encounter issues when I add versions of the item with the field. This occurs when I paste the HTML from the old version into the new version and then update the image with additional versions. The issue is that in content editor the old image remains the same even when there is an additional version created. I paste the HTML to essentially recreate an automated translation process.

The source for the image is the same in the HTML being the .ashx file extension.

I am curious if there is any way to make the images within the rich text to remain in sync in the content editor whenever the version exists for the image?

Previewing the item or visiting a published page reflects the proper functionality.

I am able to replicate the paste issue in another instance of Sitecore, but the URLs have language query string parameters so I could theoretically tap into a pipeline to rectify it there, but I'm unsure about .ashx extensions.

Comment: If you use the image picker in the editor, is the html different than the html that you posted? The image html should only have the ID and not care about the version. So it is interesting that the paste html is not working.

Comment: And does your HTML you are pasting look like this? <img alt="Words" src="-/media/26325e0c511f42f2a7a30309be27c0be.ashx" />

Comment: Yes, the HTML is the same whether pasted or inserted. One additional thing I uncovered was in editor if I simply clicked on the incorrect image it updated. This has me wondering if a pipeline corresponding to this doesn't run in this paste scenario, but I am not up-to-date on the content editor pipelines.

Comment: When performing this update, can you clear the Sitecore cache. Maybe for the rich text, it is not updating the preview in the field due to cache

Comment: I cleared the cache, but the image did not update.

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing the same issue on 9.3 and 10.3. On 1/4/24, I opened a case with Sitecore Support. They acknowledged that they can reproduce the bug, and are "are working closely with the development team to identify the possible ways to resolve or work around the problem".

So far, they have not provided a fix. But they did state this:

> To track the future status of this bug report, please use reference
> number 607329. More information about public reference numbers can be
> found here:
> https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0853187

Perhaps if more folks inquire about *bug reference number 607329*, they will increase the priority.

If/when they provide something, I will update this answer.